# How can I set default values in the constructor of an abstract class?

Tags: php

I have an abstract class that contains the __construct method like this

```
abstract class Model
{
    protected $attributes = [];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
        $this->$attributes = $attributes;
    }
}
```

Then in my concrete class I extend the abstract Model

```
class Pong extends Model
{
    
}
```

When I dump the attributes inside the constructor I get an empty array, but if I remove the default value of the constructor parameter, the Pong model has attributes. The challenge is, I want to be able to construct the concrete class both with default values and without

```
$pong = new Pong();
$pong = new Pong(['msg' => 'Hello Kitty']);
```

Comment: Does `Pong` have a constructor?

Comment: No, it inherits the constructor from the abstract class

Comment: `$this->$attributes` should be `$this->attributes`. https://3v4l.org/u6lm2

Comment: Your code actually throws an array-to-string conversion error. I suggest you improve your error reporting configuration. See [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, yeah a stupid typo, I've been starring at it for too long

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Give this a try:

I made the `$attributes` `public`, to show the results.

Note the question marks `??`.

```php
<?php

class Model
{
    public $attributes = [];

    public function __construct(array $attr = []) {
        $this->attributes['msg'] = $attr['msg'] ?? "default";
        $this->attributes['someValue'] = $attr['someValue'] ?? 'default';
    }
}

class Pong extends Model
{
    
}

$pong = new Pong();
print_r($pong->attributes);
```

Play around with the [code](https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedDependentVisitor#index.php) you see above!

Comment: Nice with the ?? didn't know I could do that